# Чи потрібено пробіл в кінці речення після скорочення / абревіатури у питальному реченні?

Tags: пунктуація

Вони знал про їхнє відношення до робітн.? Вони знал про їхнє відношення до робітн. ?

Ти пішов гуляти з П.А. ? Ти пішов гуляти з П.А.?

Answer (score 3):

За [правилами набору тексту](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83) пробіл не ставиться між словом і жодним розділовим знаком, крім тире і відкриваючих дужок чи лапок, але ставиться перед наступним словом.
Тире виділяється пробілами з обох боків, а парні знаки не мають пробіла між собою і текстом, що міститься в них.

Отже, оскільки скорочене слово є словом, то пробіл між ним і розділовим знаком не ставиться.

А от пробіл між П. і А. не завадив би, оскільки це окремі слова.

Щодо "робітн." взагалі не зрозуміло, нащо таке скорочення? Адже однозначно воно не читається.

Comment: Це лише внутрішні правила Вікіпедії, які все ж авторитетні. Я проглянув правила і не знайшов прямого підтвердження вашим словам. Було б добре якби ви навели витяги з них для підкріплення ваших слів.

Comment: Внутрішні правила ні до чого. 
При розстановці розділових знаків у тексті статей слід керуватися чинним українським правописом та правилами пунктуації української мови. При наборі кома («,»), крапка з комою («;»), двокрапка («:»), крапка («.»), знак оклику («!»), знак питання («?») і три крапки («…») ці спеціальні символи не відділяються пропуском від попереднього слова, але відділяються пропуском від наступного слова. Якщо ваша клавіатура не має цих спеціальних символів, ви можете спробувати знайти бажаний спеціальний символ в меню редагування «Спеціальні символи».

Comment: Це твердження посилається на нормативний документ:

ДСТУ 8344:2015. Інформація та документація. Видання. Основні елементи. Терміни та визначення понять. Київ: УкрНДНЦ, 2017. 39 стор. (Національний стандарт України) (чинний з 01.07.2017)

Comment: Ось з [того ж ДСТУ](https://ukrmova.iul-nasu.org.ua/dlya-avtoriv/pravyla-skorochennya-sliv.html), що підтверджує вашу думку - *вищий – вищ., але вища – не скорочують* - кома йде одразу після крапки.